# How to run a makefile in Windows?

Tags: windows, makefile

I have some demos that I downloaded and they come with a Makefile.win and a Makefile.sgi. How can I run these in Windows to compile the demos?

Comment: I should mention that I'm more of a Linux person but I need to use Windows right now, so I'm a little clueless.

Comment: Very clear guide is given [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hh-V6el8Oxk)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows

Comment: @tripleee how should we consider which is the dupe of which, here though? This question is from 2010, while the other, even if similarly votes, is from 2015.

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε The age of the duplicate is unimportant; the general rule is to take the better question, and/or the one with better answers, and make that the canonical.

Comment: Also, none of the answers here seem to adequately explain that installing `make` is a very small problem compared to actually making a Makefile work correctly on a new platform. `Makefile.sgi` sounds like something was very specific to a historic Unix platform (SGI / Irix).

Comment: @tripleee mhm, hard one then. IMO, the other question looks indeed better worded to me, but the highest score answer here looks better written.

Comment: If one is closed as a duplicate of the other, you can request a mod to merge them. But so far I have not done that.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio, run the Visual Studio Command prompt from the Start menu, change to the directory containing `Makefile.win` and type this:

```
nmake -f Makefile.win
```

You can also use the normal command prompt and run vsvars32.bat (c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools for VS2008). This will set up the environment to run nmake and find the compiler tools.

Comment: How do I run the visual studio command prompt from the start menu?

Comment: Alright I figured it out. But of course it wouldn't compile because of errors. Just my luck. Thanks though.

Comment: For those with VS2012, the command prompt is called "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012". Start--> Search--> "command" is how I found it.

Comment: @NSD: You can try other "make"s, but such files are usually written against nmake's dialect and with the assumption that VS is installed and on the path. You might find that the free [VS Express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#d-2012-express) suffices.

Comment: @MarceloCantos I am a noob to Linux and Making. What if I have .am and .mk file. I don't have any .win file. I am trying to make wget, btw.

Comment: @Cheeku: That's a different question and has little to do with programming. Why don't you just install it from whatever package manager your Linux distro has?

Comment: @MarceloCantos How to do it on Windows? Not using cygwin or GNU Make, instead using VS Developer Command Prompt

Comment: Great! how do I make nmake callabre from Windows console? just edit path variable so that it find the executable?

Comment: @TheMask: That's explained in the answer.

Comment: What about for those of us that don't have it in the start menu? navigating to the MSVS cmd prompt via the start menu is not a valid answer. I don't know the exact command it executes, but all that thing in the start menu is a shortcut to some executable with a few command line switches - none of which I remember - all of which I want to know what they are. The start menu can't help everyone

Comment: I obtained a copy of MSVS 2010 C++, and this is what the command line was for that shortcut '%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86'. This isn't quite what I remember, but either way, there it is. It looks like in this case all its doing is setting up the environment for a regular shell

Comment: @searchengine27: Afaict, it was a valid answer five years ago.

Comment: @MarceloCantos No, it was never a valid answer. Unless you're saying that the "MSVS Command Prompt" was its own individual executable, and that MSVS mandated that you always have that in the start menu (both of which I know for a fact are not true), then that was never a valid answer. Other people happening to have it in the start menu because they/their company installed it in such a fashion does not correlate to this being a valid answer. It is a helpful answer to some people, but you're confusing that with valid to the question. I suggest updating your answer to make it valid.

Comment: @searchengine27: It's a valid answer for anyone installing the product in the standard way. It has always been there for me, even in corporate environments. If some enterprise IT shop wants to do weird shit, that's their business.

Comment: If your makefile contains Linux commands as well, you cannot use this approach, you need Cygwin.

Comment: In my case, making file for libjpeg in windows, i needed for win32.mak file, you can find it at: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include\Win32.Mak"

Answer (score 236):

You can install [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) with [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install), a well-maintained package manager, which will add `make` to the global path and runs on all CLIs (powershell, git bash, cmd, etc…) saving you a ton of time in both maintenance and initial setup to get make running.

1. Install the [chocolatey package manager](https://chocolatey.org/install) for **Windows**
   <sup>*compatible to Windows 7+ / Windows Server 2003+*</sup>
2. Run `choco install make`

I am not affiliated with choco, but I highly recommend it, so far it has never let me down and I do have a talent for breaking software unintentionally.

Comment: You are amazing, thanks so much. Runs as if trying the Makefile on a native Linux environment, but in windows! Was having issues with make using WSL, for a gui Java app, but this made it work using PowerShell.

Comment: This is the best way to use make in windows, with no complication.
And working fine for my team.

Answer (score 79):

Check out [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/)'s [make *(for windows)*](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm), which provides a native port for Windows (without requiring a full runtime environment like Cygwin)

If you have [winget](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli), you can install via the CLI like this:

```sh
winget install GnuWin32.Make
```

Also, be sure to add the install path to your system `PATH`:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
```

Comment: In addition, please add "C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin" to your system PATH.

Comment: You also might want to consider changing the install directory to avoid spaces and parenthesis as they can [cause issues running the CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15080184/1366033)

Comment: I tried today on Win10, and I didn't need to add it to path.... Works! Maybe WinGet is smarter now?

Comment: It no longer finds the Make. 

`winget install GnuWin32.Make`
No package found matching input criteria.

It does see other GnuWin32 packages when doing `winget search GnuWin32`

Answer (score 69):

Check out [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), a Unix alike environment for Windows

Comment: cygwin worked well for me!. I just had to check, during installation, some packages in `Devel` :  'make' and also 'gcc' as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4828388/cygwin-make-bash-command-not-found).

Comment: I also recommend to install cygwin using chocolatey, so the command to get `make` is this: `choco install make --source=cygwin`

Comment: after I installed with choco, how can I add it to my command shell? there is a path to be added?

Comment: In case you installed it with choco, then add this line (witought quotation marks) to your path variable in the system variables "C:\tools\cygwin\bin"

Answer (score 42):

Here is my quick and temporary way to run a Makefile

- download **make** from SourceForge: [gnuwin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/make/3.81/make-3.81.exe/download?use_mirror=iweb&download=)
- install it
- go to the  install folder

> C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin

- copy the **all files** in the bin to the **folder that contains Makefile**

> libiconv2.dll  libintl3.dll  make.exe

- **open the cmd** *(you can do it with **right click with shift**)* in the folder that contains Makefile and run

> make.exe

done.

*Plus, you can add arguments after the command, such as*

> make.exe skel

Comment: It's probably better to add `bin` directory to `PATH` environment variable.
This will make `make.exe` available from anywhere.

Comment: I think its done by default - at least that was the case when I installed gnuwin32. Of course copying the files is bad practice anyway.

Comment: It is not done by default (or not in my case). By adding it to the path, then you can run _make_ from the project folder.

Comment: Work like a champ

Answer (score 9):

If you install [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/install.html). Make sure to select make in the installer. You can then run the following command provided you have a Makefile.

```
make -f Makefile

https://cygwin.com/install.html
```

Answer (score 9):

I use [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) tool set which provides `mingw32-make` build tool, if you have it in your [`PATH` system variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5733220/10404680), in Windows Command Prompt just go into the directory containing the files and type this command:

```
mingw32-make -f Makefile.win
```

and it's done.

Comment: could copy a `{mingw64 folder}/bin/mingw32-make.exe` and rename it to `make.exe`

Answer (score 8):

I tried all of the above. What helps me:

1. Download the [mingw-get](https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe/download).
2. Setup it.
3. Add something like this `C:\MinGW\bin` to environment variables.
4. Launch (!important) [git bash](https://git-scm.com/download/win). Power shell, developer vs cmd, system cmd etc didn't help.
5. Type `mingw-get` into the command line.
6. After type `mingw-get install mingw32-make`.

Done! Now You might be able to use make-commands from any folder that contains Makefile.

Answer (score 6):

With Visual Studio 2017 I had to add this folder to my Windows 10 path env variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.10.25017\bin\HostX64\x64
```

There's also HostX86

Answer (score 4):

If it is a "NMake Makefile", that is to say the syntax and command is compatible with NMake, it will work natively on Windows. Usually `Makefile.win` (the `.win` suffix) indicates it's a makefile compatible with Windows NMake. So you could try `nmake -f Makefile.win`.

Often standard Linux Makefiles are provided and `NMake` looks promising. However, the following link takes a simple Linux Makefile and explains some fundamental issues that one may encounter. It also suggests a few alternatives to handling Linux Makefiles on Windows.

[Makefiles in Windows](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/makefiles-windows/)

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, add path of visual studio common tools (`c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools`) into the system path. To learn how to add a path into system path, please check this website:
http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm. You just need to this once.

After that, whenever you need, open a command line and execute `vsvars32.bat` to add all required visual studio tools' paths into the system path.

Then, you can call `nmake -f makefile.mak`

PS: Path of visual studio common tools might be different in your system. Please change it accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with cygwin & gnuwin, and didn't worked for me, I guess because the makefile used mainly specific linux code.

What it worked was use **Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10**. This is a Marvel if you come from MAC as it is my case:

1. To install the Ubuntu Bash: https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/
2. Once in the console, to install make simply type "make" and it gives the instructions to download it.

**Extras:**

1. Useful enable copy / paste on bash: [Copy Paste in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832230/copy-paste-in-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows)
2. In my case the make called Maven, so I have to install it as well: https://askubuntu.com/questions/722993/unable-to-locate-package-maven
3. To access windows filesystem C: drive, for example: "cd /mnt/c/"

Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

If you have already installed the Windows GNU compiler (MinGW) from [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/) then `make` command comes pre-installed as `wingw32-make`. **Always match cmake makefile generation with the correct make command.** Mixing these generate problems.

> MinGW makefile generation with MinGW make command

> Visual Studio makefile generation with VS equivalent make command

And this is always possible as long as you have the source code. Just delete old build directory and start over by specifying this time the right parameter in cmake ,e.g.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW MakeFiles" path/to/src/whereCMakeLists.txtInstructionsAre   
mingw32-make     
myProject.exe   # RUN
```

I have encountered issues during compilation where multiple make commands interact. To prevent this just edit/remove the environmental variables that lead to different make commands. For example to prevent conflicts with mingw, keep only `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` but remove `C:\msys64\usr\bin`. That other path contains the msys make and as I said you do not want to combine make commands during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Install msys2 with make dependency add both to PATH variable.
(The second option is GNU ToolChain for Windows. MinGW version has already mingw32-make included.)

Install Git Bash. Run mingw32-make from Git Bash.

Comment: Thanks, this was the perfect solution for my environment. I am learning how to minimally compile big projects in Windows' VS Code with make (like I do in Linux with boost-build), but I kept struggling with cmd and Windows shell syntax.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/
2. Set the variable path in advance setting for recognize in command prompt (C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin)

Answer (score 1):

So if you're using Vscode and Mingw then you should first make sure that the `bin` folder of the `mingw` is included in the environment path and it is preferred to change the `mingw32-make.exe` to `make` to ease the task and then create a `makefile`
and include this code in it .

```
all:
    gcc -o filename filename.c
    ./filename
```

Then save the makefile and open Vscode `Code` terminal and write `make`. Then makefile will get executed.

Comment: Following this [tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) helps alot with the setup as well

Answer (score 1):

The procedure I followed is;

1. I installed Gnuwin32's make using the [installable](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/files/make/3.81/make-3.81.exe/download?use_mirror=onboardcloud&download=).
2. Added the "make" path to the environmental variable PATH.
3. Verified the installation using "make --version"

Comment: This seems to be yet another duplicate of multiple existing answers from the previous decades.

Answer (score 1):

You can also install via the Scoop package manager (similar to Chololatey). Go to [Scoop](https://scoop.sh) and search for the package you need. In this case [make](https://scoop.sh/#/apps?q=make) and paste the command for installing it.

Command to install `make` on Windows. I tested in PowerShell.

```
scoop install main/make
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you added `mingw32/bin` is added to environment variables else please add it and I am assuming it as gcc compiler and you have mingw installer.

First step: download `mingw32-make.exe` from mingw installer, or please check `mingw/bin` folder first whether `mingw32-make.exe` exists or not, else than install it, rename it to `make.exe`.

After renaming it to `make.exe`, just go and run this command in the directory where `makefile` is located. Instead of renaming it you can directly run it as `mingw32-make`.

After all, a command is just exe file or a software, we use its name to execute the software, we call it as command.

Answer (score 0):

For me installing ubuntu WSL on windows was the best option, that is the best tool for compiling makefile on windows. One thousand is better than Cygwin64, because to compile a makefile you will need another package and compile software like maybe gfortran, netcdf, etc, ect, in ubuntu WSL you can install all of these packages very easily and quickly ;)

Comment: Just WSL is a good start, but not by itself enough. On Debian-based platforms (such as Ubuntu), `apt-get install -y build-essential` will get you a build toolchain which works for many projects, including creating new Debian packages.

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/make.htm and download make-3.81.exe, install and add to Windows path.

Comment: This seems to duplicate Sean's answer from 2013.

Answer (score -12):

> May be it can work.

```
pip install Makefile
```