# How do I add the MinGW bin directory to my system path?

Tags: c++, windows

I am using Windows XP. I am trying to add a new library to [Dev-C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B). For that, I need to install MinGW and then I have been instructed to add the `bin` directory of MinGW to my system path. But, I don’t know how to do it. Please guide me (step by step) to add this to my system path.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

To change the path on Windows XP, follow [these instructions](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), and then add the directory where you install MinGW plus `bin`. Example: if you install MinGW in C:\ then you have to add `C:\mingw\bin` to your path

Just for completeness here are the steps shown on the link:

1. From the desktop, right-click *My Computer* and click *Properties*.
2. In the *System Properties* window, click on the *Advanced* tab.
3. In the *Advanced* section, click the *Environment Variables* button.
4. Finally, in the *Environment Variables* window, highlight the *Path* variable in the *Systems Variable* section and click the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button. Add or modify the path lines with the paths you wish the computer to access. Each different directory is separated with a semicolon as shown below.

   C:\Program Files;C:\Winnt;C:\Winnt\System32;c:\mingw\bin

Comment: alternatively, you can directly call `set PATH=C:\mingw\bin;%PATH%` from the cmd shell, or place the command in a batch script that sets up your environment (that's how Visual Studio does it for its CMD prompt).

Comment: You can also search "path" in the search bar and environmental variables should show up.