# lxml 2.3.4 installation error on windows xp pro

Tags: python, lxml, easy-install

I'm on windows xp pro sp 3.

OK, so basically `easy_install lxml` does not work. I've got errors like this: `Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat`. But after I downloaded and installed Visual Studio 2008 express, a new error came up: `ValueError: [u'path']`. I've searched around and couldn't find any solution for this, anybody please help me out?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear that you do not have Microsoft's compiler installed.
You have a couple of other options:

- (**recommended**) find a pre-compiled binary somewhere e.g.: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml
- download the MinGW compiler and point `easy_install` to that...

---

If you choose to install a compiler follow these instructions:

1. install MinGW compiler
2. add MinGW compiler's bin directory to your PATH env var ( detailed instructions in accepted answer to this SO question: [How do I add the MinGW bin directory to my system path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733220/how-to-add-mingw-bin-diretory-to-my-system-path) )
3. do one of the following two things:
   a. specify which compiler to use in the command-line arguments:
   `python setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32`
   b. or for a more permanent solution modify `\Lib\distutils\distutils.cfg` -- go ahead and create it if it doesn't exist -- and add this section:

```
[build]
compiler=mingw
```