# CMake does not work with g++ installed with MinGW

Tags: cmake, g++, mingw

I try to make CMake work with my setup (windows 7, 64 bits). I have installed MingGW to have a C and C++ compiler. In the configuration of CMake I entered the following :
for the C compiler : C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe
for the C++ compiler : C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe

but when trying to run CMake on a project built with a CMakeList I get the following errors:

*The program can't start because libgmp-10.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.*

Here is the full ouput:

> The CXX compiler identification is unknown Check for working CXX
>   compiler: C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe Check for working CXX compiler:
>   C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe -- broken CMake Error at C:/Program
>   Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.9/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:44
>   (message):   The C++ compiler "C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe" is not
>   able to compile a   simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> Change Dir: D:/Libraries/deformetrica/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe" "cmTC_bbc9e/fast"
>
> C:/MinGW/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_bbc9e.dir\build.make   CMakeFiles/cmTC_bbc9e.dir/build
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
>   'D:/Libraries/deformetrica/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Building CXX object
>   CMakeFiles/cmTC_bbc9e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj
>
> C:\MinGW\bin\mingw32-g++.exe -o
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_bbc9e.dir\testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj -c
>   D:\Libraries\deformetrica\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCXXCompiler.cxx
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTC_bbc9e.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_bbc9e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_bbc9e.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.obj] Error 1
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
>   'D:/Libraries/deformetrica/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_bbc9e/fast' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_bbc9e/fast] Error 2
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)
>
> Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also
>   "D:/Libraries/deformetrica/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
>   "D:/Libraries/deformetrica/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

g++ was installed with MinGW and I did not see any error on the installation so I was wondering how this could be fixed ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: You should list the full command used to invoke ```cmake```. Just cut & paste the entire terminal window, preferably including the command prompt that appeared after the program finished too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the MinGW `bin` folder to the `PATH` environment variable.

You can have a look here for the setup:
[How do I add the MinGW bin directory to my system path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733220/how-do-i-add-the-mingw-bin-directory-to-my-system-path)

Comment: I had the same problem in QtCreator. I cloned a kit. The original kit worked, the clone did not, unless I added the g++ to the path variable. Very strange. I added these variables to the kit:  
    OPENCASCADE_DIR=C:\Users\gf\Documents\opencascade  
    PATH=${OpenCASCADE_DIR}\win64\gcc\bin;${VTK_DIR}\bin;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\bin;%{Env:PATH}  
    VTK_DIR=C:\Users\gf\Documents\INSTALL\VTK