# How to compile WindRiver/Eclipse C++ projects from the command line?

Tags: c++, eclipse, command-line, compilation, makefile

I'm currently running a variant of Eclipse known as WindRiver, which is designed for embedded systems programming using C++ (specifically, I'm part of my high school's FIRST Robotics team).

I'm able to successfully compile and build the project from within Eclipse (Project > Build Project) but I'm looking for ways to automate this process by compiling by using the command line.

The project already contains a makefile and everything, so ideally I want to be able to just run that without making any manual changes. I [pastebin'd](http://pastebin.com/Bt1GyaDh) the makefile in case its relevant.

Does anybody know where I can find more information on compiling C++ programs from the command line for either Eclipse or WindRiver or on running makefiles on Windows? I tried looking at [*"How to run a makefile in Windows?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2532234/646543) but following the first answer didn't work (it gave a syntax error for the makefile).

I'm currently using a Windows 8 laptop. As best as I can tell, the current varient of WindRiver I'm using is based on Eclipse version 3.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Mat Petersson's answer, I was able to identify everything I needed and create a batch file that could compile the file for me:

```
@echo off

setlocal

set PATH=%PATH%;C:\WindRiver\gnu\3.4.4-vxworks-6.3\x86-win32\bin;C:\WindRiver\utilities-1.0\x86-win32\bin;C:\WindRiver\setup\x86-win32\bin
set WIND_BASE=C:\WindRiver\vxworks-6.3

cd My_Project\PPC603gnu

make --no-print-directory BUILD_SPEC=PPC603gnu DEBUG_MODE=1 TRACE=1
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need a make utility, I believe your WindRiver / Eclipse setup would come with "gnumake" (probably called either `make` or `gmake`). You'd nee dto set up the command line path to lead to the compiler and the make executable. Unfortunately, this is not a great answer, as I can't give you exact links to the make and compiler locations (it would of course also depend on where you installed things). I just thought I'd lead you somewhat on the right path, since the question has been up for a little while and no one jumped at it.

Comment: +1 Thank you very much: you turned out to be absolutely correct. I'll post what I found as a separate answer, in case anybody needs it (although the paths would probably be different, as you noted).