# Cygwin unexpected token `(' on cd

Tags: cygwin

I have got `Program Files` and `Program Files (x86)` directory at `C`. I can access to `Program Files` using `$ cd Program\ Files\` from windows 8 but this `$ cd Program\ Files\ (x86)` command returns following error:

```
sadaf2605@Sadaf /cygdrive/c
$ cd Program\ Files\ (x86)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to escape the parentheses as well:

```
$ cd Program\ Files\ \(x86\)
```

Or just use quotes:

```
$ cd "Program Files (x86)"
```