# sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: git, bash, command-line, command

All that I'm trying to do is `cd` into `Program Files (x86)` and I get this:

Already in the C directory:

```
$ cd Program Files (x86)

sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: @GergoErdosi looks like git bash on windows

Comment: **See Also** [Cygwin unexpected token `(` on cd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15080184/1366033)

Answer (score 11):

you need to quote the directory name or escape special characters

try

```
cd "Program Files (x86)"
```

or

```
cd Program\ Files\ \(x86\)
```

Comment: And you can also just `cd Pro<tab>` to automatically complete and escape like this

Comment: @thatotherguy Yeah, I was going to suggest that (it's what I would do myself), but it'll stick at `Program\ Files` as an ambiguous match, probably take a couple of hits of the tab key to show the possibilities, then you'll need to type `\<space>` and hit tab again...