# Bash syntax error near unexpected token '('. Windows 7

Tags: android, windows, bash, android-ndk

Trying execute ndk path for android build for hookflash demo in bash shell windows 7:

https://github.com/openpeer/opandroid

ndk path is located in windows 32 bit folder which is a requirement:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\android-ndk-r8e
```

When executing:

```
./buildall_android.sh C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\android-ndk-r8e
```

I receive the following error:

```
sh.exe": syntax error near unexpected token '('
```

I am aware that since the ndk is in 32 bit folder the parentheses around "(x86)" is the issue throwing the token error. How else can you write this command to fix this error? Thanks for your help.

Comment: **See Also** [Cygwin unexpected token `(` on cd](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15080184/1366033)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have spaces and parentheses in your path, you need to put your path in quotes:

```
./buildall_android.sh "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\android-ndk-r8e"
```

Comment: You are correct with the quotes. Thanks, I also had to change back slashes to forward slashes.