# Objective-C for Windows with Gitbash and GCC

Tags: objective-c, windows, gcc

When I compile things with gitbash and gcc, is there someway to shorten what I need to type?

In order to compile my helloworld program, I have to type the following in:

```
gcc -o helloworld.exe helloworld.m -I C:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Headers -L         C:/GNUstep/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries -std=c99 -lobjc -lgnustep-base -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString
```

Comment: [`make`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software))

Comment: I'm sorry, could you elaborate? I'm not used to using gitbash and the like I'm not sure what to do with that.

Comment: @userXXX `make` is a build automation tool. If you learn to use it, you won't need to manually invoke the compiler every time, instead you can write the command once and use `make` to call out to the compiler when necessary.

Comment: gnustep-make package is a collection of scripts and configurations you could use to build things with GNUstep. You can write a GNUmakefile and type make to process it.

Answer (score 0):

Most people use Makefiles (or something related, e.g. CMake) in order to ease development. Makefiles are similar to bash scripts (the syntax is similar as well). After you created a Makefile you can run `make` and it does exactly what you specified.

If you want to know how to run Automake on Windows, read this: [How to run a makefile in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows)