# Coverity: command line build script for basic c++ code

Tags: c++, coverity

I am working on a requirement to do instrumented build for c++ code on coverity(static code analysis tool, version 7.5.1) build server via command line. Need to execute a basic c++ code via command line, I tried using the `cov-build` command `cov-build –-dir cov-int cl /c test.cpp` and various other permutations on the directory where coverity is actually installed in the build machine. But there is some problem. System can understand only the `cov-buld --dir` and if i use only this command along with `/c`, this file opens in visual studio rather than giving the`%` of compilation units.
Please help me if anyone have done this before.

Comment: cov-build requires two mandatory parameters
cov-build --dir <intermediate_directory> <build_command> 
Have you provided intermediate_directory name? what is cov-int in the command mentioned by you?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, cov-int is our intermediate directory at the server for the respective project. Can you please tell me cl /c is a build command in coverity?  Because every time I am getting the same error that cl is not a build command. for cov-int I am giving the complete directiry after dir.

Comment: on the same location where I have created this .cpp file a folder is created with name co-int which contains build-id, build-log, build cwd etc..

Comment: cl /c is not any command in coverity, its a compiler name, you have to provide your build command as a second parameter. We use gmake command, cov-build --dir<intermediate directory> gmake -s release .

Answer (score 0):

First be clear with your requirements. Which system you are working on?(windows or Mac or Unix or Solaris). Before starting cov-build, configure the compiler which will execute the source file. As you said you are working on C++ source code, use GCC compiler to configure with Coverity Static Analyzer. Coverity Directly supports for 3 Compilers(Gcc and 2 more). To configure this GCC use cov-configure command followed by gcc.

Then use cov-build command to analyze.

Sample command is:

```
path_to_cov_bin/cov-build --dir path_to_output_folder gcc hi.cpp
```

It will create emit folder with emit-db in path_to_output_folder. Then cov-analyze command will be analyze that emit folder and create Output Directory in given path.

To compile N number of source files use makefile. If you have any query about makefile You can put a post here or refer in this site.

Comment: Hi, I am working on windows. This compiler is already configured in the machine, I can see it in the coverity wizard so do i need to configure it again on command line ? Also when I am running the command suggested by you to configure the compiler system is giving the error: "you didn't specify a compiler".

Comment: path_to_cov_bin/cov-configure --gcc    @GitanshuAmola

Comment: To compile more than one source file use makefile. Refer how to use makefile in windows @ [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows]

Comment: After you use the command cov-configure --gcc, It will show that you configured GCC compiler successfully.

Comment: As expected system told that the compiler is already configured. So gcc is configured that is clear now.

Comment: Then I again tried to execute the command "path_to_cov_bin/cov-build --dir D:\Test gcc test.cpp", but system is now giving error that gcc is not a build command.

Comment: here D:\Test is my output folder and test.cpp is my cpp file.

Comment: path_to_cov_bin/cov-build --dir D:\Test gcc test.cpp In this command you have to add path of the test.cpp file.

Comment: Example: path_to_cov_bin/cov-build --dir D:\Test gcc path_to_the_file/test.cpp

Comment: I was making one mistake. This command executed in visual studio command prompt !!! "<path of Coverity bin folder>cov-build  --dir <path of intermediate directory> cl /c <path of cpp file>test.cpp”.