# How to run makefile on Windows?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmd, mingw, sdl

I have looked at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows) on stackoverflow and they said to use the command prompt called "Developer Command Prompt for VS2012" and run this command:

```
nmake -f Makefile.win
```

This was the error I got.

[image]

It says g++ is not recognized but I have it installed. Does anyone know what is wrong?

[image]

Comment: Can you run `g++` at the command-line?

Comment: I know this sounds stupid, but how can I test it out?

Comment: open `cmd.exe` and try it out by writing `g++`.

Comment: Use full path to g++, like `"C:\mingw64\mingw64\bin\g++.exe"`

Comment: it says that it isnt recognized. Does this mean I have to change my system variables?

Comment: Either write the full path to `g++` in your *Makefile* as already suggested, or modify the `PATH` environment variable so that, `g++` can be found by just writing "`g++`".

Comment: First thing first, make sure you have `g++` installed. (It doesn't come with Visual Studio, you have to do it on your own.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to *environment variables* window (using the research bar of Windows).
2. Edit `Path` variable adding the full path of where g++ is installed (do not include `g++.exe` at the end).

Save, run cmd and try again to use your makefile.

Comment: thank you. now g++ is working but i get an error saying that `nmake is not a recognized command`

Comment: This is strange since it was recognized just before (as it attempted to access gcc.exe). Didn't you remove anything from the `Path` variable?

Comment: i apologize. it works but i now have a different error. https://imgur.com/a/jqiWU

Comment: @Zolly you need to install sdl-config (and put it on the PATH).