# NIST Statistical Test Suite

Tags: makefile

I have downloaded NIST Statistical Test Suite version 2.1.2 from nist website. The package contains a **makefile**. How to compile the project (makefile) on windows?

Answer (score 4):

As I have faced the same question, I would like to add my solution. On Windows you can use [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) which allows you to compile C language. You can follow the bellow steps:

**Installing Cygwin**

1. Let "**install root directory**" be "**c:/cygwin**".
2. Choose the nearest mirror site for download.
3. Choose packages, and download them. In addition to Default choose (**gcc** and **make**) packages.

**Running NIST tests**

4. Open **Cygwin Terminal**.
5. Navigate to the [NIST Statistical Test Suite](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/random-bit-generation/documentation-and-software)'s folder. Lets say you have unzipped the folders in ***E*** drive . Write: **cd /cygdrive/E/NIST** Now you are in NIST folder
6. Run the **makefile** by writing **make -f Makefile**, this will creates the **assess** file.
7. Now run the **assess** file by writing **./assess 100000** and follow the prompted steps.

Answer (score 0):

Before compiling the project, make sure you follow the User's guide (5th section from the [specifications](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-22r1a.pdf)) and especially 5.3.

Also make sure you

> Edit the makefile. Modify the following lines:
>
> (a) CC (your ANSI C compiler)
>
> (b) ROOTDIR (the root directory that was prescribed earlier in the process, e.g.,
> rng/)

If you are looking for a way to execute makefiles on windows, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows).