# How to build NLopt on Windows

Tags: makefile, cmake, nmake, nlopt

I'm trying to build [NLopt](https://github.com/stevengj/nlopt) on Windows. To do so, I open *Visual Studio 2017 Developer Command Prompt* and then:

```
>cd C:\Users\m3\repos\
>git clone git://github.com/stevengj/nlopt
>cd nlopt
>mkdir build
>cd build
>cmake ..
```

Then I need to run commands `make` and `sudo make install`. Of course, Windows doesn't have GNU make, so I want to use Windows [nmake as suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2532239/3405291). But there I cannot find any proper Makefile to use. Am I missing something?

This is the *build* directory content after running `cmake ..` command:

```
>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 3874-53A8

 Directory of C:\Users\m3\repos\nlopt\build

10/06/2020  09:45 AM    <DIR>          .
10/06/2020  09:45 AM    <DIR>          ..
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            51,498 ALL_BUILD.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               278 ALL_BUILD.vcxproj.filters
10/06/2020  09:44 AM    <DIR>          build_fpclassify
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            24,269 CMakeCache.txt
10/06/2020  09:45 AM    <DIR>          CMakeFiles
10/06/2020  09:45 AM             7,196 cmake_install.cmake
10/06/2020  09:45 AM             3,449 CPackConfig.cmake
10/06/2020  09:45 AM             3,690 CPackSourceConfig.cmake
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               308 CTestTestfile.cmake
10/06/2020  09:44 AM                99 fpclassify.c
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            57,561 generate-cpp.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               964 generate-cpp.vcxproj.filters
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            57,576 generate-fortran.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               967 generate-fortran.vcxproj.filters
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            11,841 INSTALL.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               520 INSTALL.vcxproj.filters
10/06/2020  09:45 AM    <DIR>          Matlab
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            10,624 nlopt.sln
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            79,777 nlopt.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM             9,916 nlopt.vcxproj.filters
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               904 NLoptConfig.cmake
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               388 NLoptConfigVersion.cmake
10/06/2020  09:45 AM             3,463 NLoptLibraryDepends.cmake
10/06/2020  09:45 AM             4,955 nlopt_config.h
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            12,073 PACKAGE.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               520 PACKAGE.vcxproj.filters
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            11,315 RUN_TESTS.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               522 RUN_TESTS.vcxproj.filters
10/06/2020  09:45 AM    <DIR>          src
10/06/2020  09:45 AM    <DIR>          test
10/06/2020  09:45 AM            50,952 ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj
10/06/2020  09:45 AM               521 ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj.filters
              27 File(s)        406,146 bytes
               7 Dir(s)  274,515,578,880 bytes free
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally built it by opening the `nlopt.sln` Visual Studio Solution file inside `build` directory by Visual Studio. Then, using the menu `Build > Build Solution` for both debug and release modes ...

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Hi! Following your footsteps. Wanted to ask what to do after I build the dll. How do I register it? Whatever I do, nloptr library in R says "nlopt.h not found"

Comment: @АрсенГоян I was using C++ not R.

Comment: For anyone who comes here for the answer for R, put the .h file in ${R_INSTALL_DIR}\include