# How to install NLopt on Windows?

Tags: windows, installation, nlopt

I'm having a very hard time trying to install [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) on Windows. I have managed to install it using [Ubuntu on WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl), but that doesn't really work for me, I have to have it installed on Windows.

In NLopt documentation, instructions for installation are provided [here](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Installation/) and specific instructions for installation on Windows are provided [here](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_on_Windows/). I've tried everything but just can't make it work.

I want to use it on C++, and I have even followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64220349/how-to-build-nlopt-on-windows) on how to build the project on Windows using Visual Studio, and have managed to get all the steps right until there without problems. After building the way it was suggested, I could see a `nlopt.hpp` inside `~/nlopt/build/`, but there is no `nlopt.h` there. So when I include `#include "nlopt.hpp"` and try to compile my code, I get the errors "E1696: cannot open source file nlopt.h" and "C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nlopt.h': No such file or directory". Of course it will give me errors, because the `.h` file simply doesn't exist. But I don't know what else to do.

Can anyone help me? I would really appreciate if a step-by-step solution could be provided from the very beggining. Thanks a lot in advance!