# ERROR: Failed building wheel for apriltag

Tags: python, pip, robotics, apriltags

I'm trying to pip install apriltag, but am getting the error `ERROR: Failed building wheel for apriltag`. I've seen several posts on failure building wheel but can't seem to find one that gives a solution to my particular problem. I do have 'wheel' installed. I also have opencv already installed and working via `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

Here is the entire output when I do `pip install apriltag`

```
Collecting apriltag
  Using cached apriltag-0.0.16.tar.gz (201 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: apriltag
  Building wheel for apriltag (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ajord\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ajord\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-miy_0730'
       cwd: C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\
  Complete output (82 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  copying python\apriltag.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
  running build_ext
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30138.0
  -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30138.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting C compile features
  -- Detecting C compile features - done
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
  -- Detecting CXX compile features
  -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
  CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_minimum_required):
    Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
    CMake.

    Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
    CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


  -- Looking for pthread.h
  -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
  -- Found Threads: TRUE
  -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
  -- Checking for one of the modules 'opencv>=2.3;opencv-2.3.1;opencv-3.0.0'
  -- Configuring done
  -- Generating done
  CMake Warning:
    Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

      PYTHON_EXECUTABLE


  -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/ajord/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b1vg4v5/apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release
  Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(517,5): warning 
MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
    Checking Build System
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(517,5): warning 
MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\core\apriltag.vcxproj]
    Building Custom Rule C:/Users/ajord/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b1vg4v5/apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58/core/CMakeLists.txt
  cl : command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wsign-compare' [C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\core\apriltag.vcxproj]
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\setup.py", line 74, in <module>
      py_modules=['apriltag']
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 299, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\setup.py", line 35, in run      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\setup.py", line 60, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '--build', '.'] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp)
    File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for apriltag
  Running setup.py clean for apriltag
Failed to build apriltag
Installing collected packages: apriltag
    Running setup.py install for apriltag ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ajord\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ajord\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4ys0zukh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\Include\apriltag'
         cwd: C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\
    Complete output (84 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    copying python\apriltag.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7
    running build_ext
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 16 2019
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19043.
    -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30138.0
    -- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.29.30138.0
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting C compile features
    -- Detecting C compile features - done
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
    -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
    -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - skipped
    -- Detecting CXX compile features
    -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
    CMake Deprecation Warning at CMakeLists.txt:3 (cmake_minimum_required):
      Compatibility with CMake < 2.8.12 will be removed from a future version of
      CMake.

      Update the VERSION argument <min> value or use a ...<max> suffix to tell
      CMake that the project does not need compatibility with older versions.


    -- Looking for pthread.h
    -- Looking for pthread.h - not found
    -- Found Threads: TRUE
    -- Could NOT find PkgConfig (missing: PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE)
    -- Checking for one of the modules 'opencv>=2.3;opencv-2.3.1;opencv-3.0.0'
    -- Configuring done
    -- Generating done
    CMake Warning:
      Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

        PYTHON_EXECUTABLE


    -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/ajord/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b1vg4v5/apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58/build/temp.win-amd64-3.7/Release
    Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.11.2+f32259642 for .NET Framework
    Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(517,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj]
      Checking Build System
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(517,5): warning MSB8029: The Intermediate directory or Output directory cannot reside under the Temporary directory as it could lead to issues with incremental build. [C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\core\apriltag.vcxproj]
      Building Custom Rule C:/Users/ajord/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-6b1vg4v5/apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58/core/CMakeLists.txt
    cl : command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/Wsign-compare' [C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\build\temp.win-amd64-3.7\Release\core\apriltag.vcxproj]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\setup.py", line 74, in <module>
        py_modules=['apriltag']
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\setup.py", line 35, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\setup.py", line 60, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(['cmake', '--build', '.'] + build_args, cwd=self.build_temp)
      File "C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\lib\subprocess.py", line 363, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', '--build', '.', '--config', 'Release', '--', '/m']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\ajord\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\ajord\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-6b1vg4v5\\apriltag_f89b201aaba74149b125992ed282bd58\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\ajord\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-4ys0zukh\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\ajord\miniconda3\envs\vision\Include\apriltag' Check the logs for full command output.
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your error log, your actual error is: "invalid numeric argument '/Wsign-compare'"

...which makes this question a duplicate of [invalid numeric argument '/Wsign-compare' : Can't install pip package or build corresponding library on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65481821)