# migration makefile (C) in linux to makefile in windows

Tags: makefile, nmake

I'm very new to Makefiles and I try to migrate this Makefile written for Linux (make) to a windows environment (nmake). I did not write this file so obviously I'm also trying to figure out the meaning of those lines.

Any chance you'd help me with the "translation" ?

```
DIR = src


BIN_PATH_DEST = /usr/local/bin
LIB_PATH_DEST = /usr/local/libs

CFLAGS = -DDISPLAY_TIME -DWRITE_TXT_FILES -DDISPLAY_BOUNDINGBOX

libs/libenvis3D_co.a:
    cd $(DIR); make CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" ../libs/libenvis3D_co.a

bin/geobox_envis3D_co: main3D_co.c libs/libenvis3D_co.a
    gcc -Wall $(CFLAGS) main3D_co.c libs/libenvis3D_co.a -lm -llapack -o bin/geobox_envis3D_co

install3D_co: bin/geobox_envis3D_co
    cd $(DIR); make CFLAGS="$(CFLAGS)" ../libs/libenvis3D_co.a
    make bin/geobox_envis3D_co
    cp bin/geobox_envis3D_co $(BIN_PATH_DEST)

clean:
    cd $(DIR); make clean
```

I also tried to download and use GNU make as described in this page :
[How to run a makefile in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows)
but I'm being throw the error :

```
C:\users\...>make -f Makefile
cd src; make CFLAGS="-DDISPLAY_TIME -DWRITE_TXT_FILES -DDISPLAY_BOUNDINGBOX" ../libs/libenvis3D_co.a
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable. (path to file not found).
make: *** [libs/libenvis3D_co.a] Erreur 1
```

Thanks for your input and help !

Comment: `nmake` is not an implementation of POSIX make.  It's a fairly different, incompatible tool that has a similar name.

Comment: Agreed, that's why I'm trying to translate it to be nmake compatible, or GNU make compatible, which I expected to work better tbh

Comment: That is not a standalone makefile.  It relies on another one residing in subdirectory `src`.  It also assumes compilation with gcc, which would be unusual on Windows (but not out of the question).  There is a variety of other reasons why a Makefile intended for a POSIX environment might not work in Windows, even with GNU `make`.  These are consequences of differences between the two environments and the specifics of the makefile(s), not attributable to `make` itself.

Comment: It's not enough to use a compatible make.  Makefiles are just tools that run other commands.  You also have to port the commands make runs.  Linux (and MacOS) are POSIX systems and use a POSIX shell, and make runs its commands in a POSIX shell.  Windows doesn't have a POSIX shell (by default), it has command.com which is not compatible.  So, make commands that rely on POSIX shell syntax, like `cd src; make ...` won't work on Windows unless you either rewrite them for command.com or else install a POSIX shell and get make to use it instead.

Comment: consider using `Msys2` environment