# Cannot compile Makefile using make command on Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, makefile, compilation

## Problem summary

I am trying to install an open-source parallel finite-element code called TACS and available at [this github repository](https://github.com/smdogroup/tacs). To comply with the indicated prerequisites, I followed the instructions at [this github repository](https://github.com/jlblancoc/suitesparse-metis-for-windows), which allowed me to install [SuiteSparse](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) and [METIS](http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/views/metis) on Windows with precompiled BLAS/LAPACK DLLs. For the MPI, I installed both the Intel MPI Library and Open MPI through Cygwin. The final step should be to compile running `make`, however this command is not directly available in Windows 10. As a consequence, I explored the options suggested in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows), unfortunately without success. I feel at a dead end, any help will be appreciated.

## What I've tried

Please have a look below at my attempts. I am mainly a Windows user and I don't know much of compiling programs using `Makefile`. My current understanding is that the `Makefile` that I am trying to compile is written for Linux and whatever GNU compiler for Windows I use will not work because of the different syntax needed. Please correct me if I am wrong. What I can't understand is why I get errors also when I try to compile with Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10 (last attempt of the list below).

### Visual Studio `nmake`

Running the Developer Command Prompt for VS 2019 as administrator, I typed `nmake -f Makefile` in TACS base directory and I got `Makefile.in(28) : fatal error U1001: syntax error : illegal character '{' in macro Stop.`

[image]

### Chocolatey `make`

Running Windows Command Prompt as administrator with `C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin` at the top of  `PATH` environment variable, I typed `make` in TACS base directory and I got

```
"" was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [Makefile:23: default] Error 255
```

[image]

### Cygwin `make`

Running Windows Command Prompt as administrator with `C:\cygwin64\bin` at the top of `PATH` environment variables, I typed `make` in TACS base directory and I got three types of error:

```
error: expected ',' or '...' before numeric constant
error: cannot convert 'int*' to 'idx_t*' {aka 'long int*'}
error: no matching function for call to 'TACSSchurMat::getBCSRMat(BCSRMat**, NULL, NULL, NULL)'
```

I tried to change some variable names in the affected scripts (like `N_` in place of `_N`) and I got rid of the first and the third type of error, but not of the second one.

[image]

[image]

[image]

### GnuWin `make`

Running Windows Command Prompt as administrator with `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin` at the top of `PATH` environment variables, I typed `make` in TACS base directory and I got

```
"" was unexpected at this time.
make: *** [Makefile:23: default] Error 255
```

[image]

### MinGW `mingw32-make`

Running Windows Command Prompt as administrator with `C:\MinGW\bin` at the top of `PATH` environment variables, I typed `mingw32-make` in TACS base directory and I got

```
"" was unexpected at this time.
Makefile:23: recipe for target 'default' failed
mingw32-make: *** [default] Error 255
```

[image]

### MSYS MinGW 64-bit `make`

Running Windows Command Prompt as administrator with `C:\msys64\usr\bin` at the top of `PATH` environment variables, I typed `make` in TACS base directory and I got

```
make[1]: mpicxx: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [../TACS_Common.mk:28: C:/Users/qa21944/git/tacs/src/TACSAssembler.o] Error 127
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: mpicxx: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [../TACS_Common.mk:28: C:/Users/qa21944/git/tacs/src/TACSCreator.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs/src'
make: *** [Makefile:23: default] Error 1
```

This is quite difficult for me to understand, as the `mpicxx` file is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mpi\latest\bin`, which in turn is in the `PATH` environment variable. When I tried to add `C:\cygwin64\bin` to `PATH` (below `C:\msys64\usr\bin`) and to rerun `make`, I got

```
      0 [main] opal_wrapper (14432) C:\cygwin64\bin\opal_wrapper.exe: *** fatal error - cygheap base mismatch detected - 0x180352408/0x180357408.
This problem is probably due to using incompatible versions of the cygwin DLL.
Search for cygwin1.dll using the Windows Start->Find/Search facility
and delete all but the most recent version.  The most recent version *should*
reside in x:\cygwin\bin, where 'x' is the drive on which you have
installed the cygwin distribution.  Rebooting is also suggested if you
are unable to find another cygwin DLL.
```

I tried to follow these instructions and then rebooted my computer, but nothing changed.

[image]

[image]

### Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10 `make`

This attempt was inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60737395/6583606). I downloaded Ubuntu from Microsoft Store and installed `make`. From the Ubuntu Bash I typed `make` in TACS base directory and I got

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs/src'
Makefile:26: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs/src'
make: *** [Makefile:23: default] Error 1
```

I do not understand why I should get this error. I also made sure that all lines started with a tab rather than white spaces, but nothing changed.

[image]

## Codes

Below you can find the `Makefile.in` and `Makefile` that I am using.

### Makefile.in

```
# Do not modify this file. Copy this file to Makefile.in and then modify it.

# In order to get TACS to compile, you'll need to fill in the
# following path information. Some of the items below are required
# only if you're going to use the python interface.

# the full path to the root TACS directory
TACS_DIR = C:/Users/qa21944/git/tacs
CXX = mpicxx
RM = rm -f
PYTHON = python
PYTHON_CONFIG = python-config

# Set up for parallel make
MAKE = make -j 8

# Set the ar flags
AR_FLAGS = rcs

# Flags for debugging and regular compilation versions
EXTRA_DEBUG_CC_FLAGS = -fPIC -g 
EXTRA_CC_FLAGS = -fPIC -O3

# Use this if you have problems with mpich
# TACS_DEF = -DMPICH_IGNORE_CXX_SEEK

# Defines whether to use static or dynamic linking
# TACS_LD_CMD=${TACS_DIR}/lib/libtacs.a
TACS_LD_CMD=-L${TACS_DIR}/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,${TACS_DIR}/lib -ltacs

# For linux systems, use the following settings:
SO_EXT=so
SO_LINK_FLAGS=-fPIC -shared

# For MAC OS X, use the following settings:
# SO_EXT=so
# SO_LINK_FLAGS=-fPIC -dynamiclib

# This uses the default installation of LAPACK. 
# Use an optimized version of LAPACK if available.
# You may also have to include -lblas as well.

LAPACK_LIBS = -LC:/SP_ROOT/lapack_windows/x64 -llapack -lpthread -lblas

# For MAC OSX use the accelerate framework
# LAPACK_LIBS=-framework accelerate

# METIS is handy for partitioning graphs, but can be problematic for
# compilation.  If you compile METIS using a C++ compiler you must add
# -DTACS_CPLUSPLUS_METIS to the TACS_DEF arguments below. If you
# compile METIS using a C compiler, there should be no issues.

METIS_INCLUDE = -IC:/SP_ROOT/build/install/include
METIS_LIB = -LC:/SP_ROOT/build/install/lib -lmetis

# AMD is a set of routines for ordering matrices. It is not required by default.

AMD_INCLUDE = -IC:/SP_ROOT/build/install/include/suitesparse
AMD_LIBS = -LC:/SP_ROOT/build/install/lib -llibamd
```

### Makefile

```
# ============================================
#
# Make file for TACS_DIR/
#
# ============================================

include Makefile.in
include TACS_Common.mk

TACS_SUBDIRS = src \
    src/bpmat \
    src/elements \
    src/elements/dynamics \
    src/elements/basis \
    src/elements/shell \
    src/constitutive \
    src/functions \
    src/io

TACS_OBJS := $(addsuffix /*.o, ${TACS_SUBDIRS})

default:
    @if [ "${TACS_IS_COMPLEX}" = "true" ]; then \
       echo "Building Complex TACS"; \
       for subdir in $(TACS_SUBDIRS) ; do \
          echo "making $@ in $$subdir"; \
          echo; (cd $$subdir && $(MAKE) TACS_DIR=${TACS_DIR} TACS_DEF="${TACS_DEF} -DTACS_USE_COMPLEX") || exit 1; \
            done \
    else \
       echo "Building Real TACS"; \
       for subdir in $(TACS_SUBDIRS) ; do \
          echo "making $@ in $$subdir"; \
          echo; (cd $$subdir && $(MAKE) TACS_DIR=${TACS_DIR}) || exit 1; \
            done \
    fi
    ${CXX} ${SO_LINK_FLAGS} ${TACS_OBJS} ${TACS_EXTERN_LIBS} -o ${TACS_DIR}/lib/libtacs.${SO_EXT}
    @if [ "${TACS_IS_COMPLEX}" = "true" ]; then \
        echo "ctypedef complex TacsScalar" > tacs/TacsTypedefs.pxi; \
        echo "TACS_NPY_SCALAR = np.NPY_CDOUBLE" > tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
        echo "dtype = complex" >> tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
    else \
        echo "ctypedef double TacsScalar" > tacs/TacsTypedefs.pxi; \
        echo "TACS_NPY_SCALAR = np.NPY_DOUBLE" > tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
        echo "dtype = np.double" >> tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
    fi

debug:
    @if [ "${TACS_IS_COMPLEX}" = "true" ]; then \
       echo "Building Complex TACS"; \
       for subdir in $(TACS_SUBDIRS) ; do \
          echo "making $@ in $$subdir"; \
          echo; (cd $$subdir && $(MAKE) debug TACS_DIR=${TACS_DIR} TACS_DEF="${TACS_DEF} -DTACS_USE_COMPLEX") || exit 1; \
            done \
    else \
       echo "Building Real TACS"; \
       for subdir in $(TACS_SUBDIRS) ; do \
          echo "making $@ in $$subdir"; \
          echo; (cd $$subdir && $(MAKE) debug TACS_DIR=${TACS_DIR}) || exit 1; \
            done \
    fi
    ${CXX} ${SO_LINK_FLAGS} ${TACS_OBJS} ${TACS_EXTERN_LIBS} -o ${TACS_DIR}/lib/libtacs.${SO_EXT}
    @if [ "${TACS_IS_COMPLEX}" = "true" ]; then \
        echo "ctypedef complex TacsScalar" > tacs/TacsTypedefs.pxi; \
        echo "TACS_NPY_SCALAR = np.NPY_CDOUBLE" > tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
        echo "dtype = complex" >> tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
    else \
        echo "ctypedef double TacsScalar" > tacs/TacsTypedefs.pxi; \
        echo "TACS_NPY_SCALAR = np.NPY_DOUBLE" > tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
        echo "dtype = np.double" >> tacs/TacsDefs.pxi; \
    fi

interface:
    ${PYTHON} setup.py build_ext --inplace

complex_interface:
    ${PYTHON} setup.py build_ext --inplace --define TACS_USE_COMPLEX

complex: TACS_IS_COMPLEX=true
complex: default

complex_debug: TACS_IS_COMPLEX=true
complex_debug: debug

clean:
    ${RM} lib/libtacs.a lib/libtacs.so
    ${RM} tacs/*.so tacs/*.cpp
    @for subdir in $(TACS_SUBDIRS) ; do \
      echo "making $@ in $$subdir"; \
      echo; \
         (cd $$subdir && $(MAKE) $@ TACS_DIR=${TACS_DIR}) || exit 1; \
    done
```

**Edit:** I am adding a snippet of `TACS_Common.mk` as requested in the comments.

### TACS_Common.mk

```
TACS_LIB = ${TACS_DIR}/lib/libtacs.a

TACS_INCLUDE = -I${TACS_DIR}/src \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/bpmat \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/elements \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/elements/dynamics \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/elements/basis \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/elements/shell \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/constitutive \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/functions \
    -I${TACS_DIR}/src/io

# Set the command line flags to use for compilation
TACS_OPT_CC_FLAGS = ${TACS_DEF} ${EXTRA_CC_FLAGS} ${METIS_INCLUDE} ${AMD_INCLUDE} ${TACS_INCLUDE}
TACS_DEBUG_CC_FLAGS = ${TACS_DEF} ${EXTRA_DEBUG_CC_FLAGS} ${METIS_INCLUDE} ${AMD_INCLUDE} ${TACS_INCLUDE}

# By default, use the optimized flags
TACS_CC_FLAGS = ${TACS_OPT_CC_FLAGS}

# Set the linking flags to use
TACS_EXTERN_LIBS = ${AMD_LIBS} ${METIS_LIB} ${LAPACK_LIBS}
TACS_LD_FLAGS = ${EXTRA_LD_FLAGS} ${TACS_LD_CMD} ${TACS_EXTERN_LIBS}

# This is the one rule that is used to compile all the
# source code in TACS
%.o: %.cpp
    ${CXX} ${TACS_CC_FLAGS} -c $< -o $*.o
    @echo
    @echo "        --- Compiled $*.cpp successfully ---"
    @echo
```

Comment: You lack one file in your description: `TACS_common.mk` is not shown and it's included from your `Makefile`.  Please, add it to the question, or it will be difficult (as the `Makefile` is very complex) to give you hints about how to solve it.

Comment: @LuisColorado thanks for your comment, I have added the file.

Comment: The error _target pattern contains no '%'_ is almost certainly a problem of using drive letters as I mentioned below.  Because of them a rule is being interpreted as a static pattern rule, and static pattern rules require `%` pattern matching chars.  But, that error is in the `src/Makefile` at line 26 so you'll have to look there for details of where the problem pathname is coming from.

Comment: @MadScientist you were right, correcting the paths with an appropriate syntax the error disappeared. What I did next was to install all prerequisites through Ubuntu for Windows 10 (which is indeed a WSL) and try again to compile with `make`. Now I get errors that look like `/usr/bin/ld: src/TACSBuckling.o:TACSBuckling.c:(.text+0x344): undefined reference to \`__getreent'`, `/usr/bin/ld: src/TACSAuxElements.o:TACSAuxElements.cpp:(.xdata+0x10): undefined reference to \`__gxx_personality_seh0'`, etc. However this looks a bit out of the scope of my original question, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't answer but maybe I can orient you.

First `nmake` is not make.  It will not work with any makefile not written specifically as an nmake makefile.  And it's only available on Windows.  So, best to just forget it exists.

Second, it's important to understand how make works: rules in makefiles are a combination of targets/prerequisites, and a recipe.  The recipe is not in "makefile" syntax, it's a shell script (batch file).  So make works in tandem with the shell, to run commands.  Which shell?  On POSIX systems like GNU/Linux and MacOS it's very simple: a POSIX shell; by default `/bin/sh`.

On Windows systems it's much less simple: there are a lot of options.  It could be `cmd.exe`.  It could be PowerShell.  It could be a POSIX shell, that was installed by the user.  Which one is chosen by default, depends on how your version of `make` was compiled.  That's why you see different behaviors for different "ports" of `make` to Windows.

So, if you look at the makefiles you are trying to use you can see they are unquestionably written specifically for a POSIX system and expect a POSIX shell and a POSIX environment.  Any attempt to use a version of `make` that invokes `cmd.exe` as its default shell will fail immediately with syntax errors (*"" was unexpected at this time.*).

OK, so you find a version of make that invokes a POSIX shell, and you don't get that error anymore.

But then you have to contend with another difference: directory separators.  In Windows they use backslash.  In POSIX systems, they use forward slash and backslash is an escape character (so it's not just passed through the shell untouched).  If you are going to use paths in a POSIX shell, you need to make sure your paths use forward slashes else the shell will remove them as escape characters.  Luckily, most Windows programs accept forward slashes as well as backslashes as directory separators (but not all: for example `cmd.exe` built-in tools do not).

Then you have to contend with the Windows abomination known as drive letters.  This is highly problematic for `make` because to `make`, the `:` character is special in various places.  So when make sees a line like `C:/foo:C:/bar` its parser will get confused, and you get errors.  Some versions of `make` compiled for Windows enable a heuristic which tries to see if a path looks like a drive letter or not.  Some just assume POSIX-style paths.  They can also be a problem for the POSIX shell: many POSIX environments on Windows map drive letters to standard POSIX paths, so `C:\foo` is written as `/c/foo` or `/mnt/c/foo` or something else.  If you are adding paths to your makefile you need to figure out what the right mapping, if any, is and use that.

That's not even to start discussing the other differences between POSIX and Windows... there are so many.

From what you've shown above, this project was not written with any sort of portability to Windows in mind.  Given the complexity of this, that's not surprising: it takes a huge amount of work.  So you have these options that I can see:

1. Port it yourself to be Windows-compatible
2. Try to get it working inside cygwin (cygwin is intended to be a POSIX-style environment that runs on Windows)
3. Try to get it working in WSL
4. Install a virtual machine using VMWare, VirtualBox, etc. running a Linux distribution and build and run it there

Unfortunately I don't know much about the pros and cons of these approaches so I can't advise you as to the best course.

The route I chose, long long ago, was to get rid of Windows entirely and just use GNU/Linux.  But of course that won't be possible for everyone :).

Comment: Well, first of all thanks for your detailed explanation, now I know a little bit more about what I am trying to do! Regarding the options that you suggest:
1. Even if it would be very interesting to learn how to port such a project to Windows (I do not have any competence at the moment), I fear it would be too time consuming for my final scope, that is using the finite-element code
2. I tried using cygwin, please have a look at my attempts. Considering your discussion, should I use a different shell rather than `cmd.exe`? If so, which one?

Comment: 3. Does Ubuntu Bash for Windows 10 classify as WSL? If so (for my understanding it does, please correct me if I am wrong), could you have a look at the last of my attemps, where I show the error I get trying to compile with Ubuntu Bash `make` command?
4. I guess this would be the option to go for if there is no other way to compile the code. Regarding the route you chose, it's something that, despite appealing, unfortunately I cannot do because in my University we use a lot of tools from Microsoft suite. What would be the best option to work with both Windows and GNU/Linux in your opinion?

Comment: Update: I tried using cygwin with Cygwin64 Terminal, but I get the same error I was getting when running from `cmd.exe` (please see the related attempt in my question).

Comment: I don't know the answers to your questions.  As I said, I don't know much about the pros and cons.  I don't use Windows and can't advise you on details of the best way to build POSIX software on Windows.  I have no idea if Bash for Windows is the same as WSL: I've never used either one.  You can look up WSL via Google and see if its installation is different than Bash for Windows.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because getting it to work in WSL was the solution that worked for me following the steps indicated in this script: https://github.com/smdogroup/tacs/blob/master/.github/workflows/unit_tests.yml

Answer (score 0):

You need a real answer: you can't compile using the Windows Command Prompt.

Get yourself MSYS2 -- which will also install MinGW-w64 -- and follow the setup instructions. Then launch the MSYS shell to get a unix-y terminal prompt (zsh, IIRC), and change directory to the head of the project folder.

To access the Windows filesystem the root directory will be either `/c` or `/mnt/c` (sorry, on my mobile ATM, I can improve this in a day or two). For example,

```
C:\Users\qa21944\git\tacs
```

becomes

```
/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs
```

From there the GNU/Windows make command should work:

```
mingw32-make
```

There is also this post to use more modern *nix environments under Windows:
[How to install and use "make" in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127524/how-to-install-and-use-make-in-windows)
Thanks may be overkill for what you need, though.

When I finish traveling and can sit down to look at this properly I can improve this answer's details, but getting a Linux shell terminal is what you need.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have just tried using MSYS2 MinGW 64-bit shell and following your indications, but unfortunately I get the following error:
`make[1]: mpicxx: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [../TACS_Common.mk:28: C:/Users/qa21944/git/tacs/src/TACSAssembler.o] Error 127
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/Users/qa21944/git/tacs/src'
mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:23: default] Error 1`
Why is that? I have both `C:\cygwin64\bin` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\oneAPI\mpi\latest\bin\`` in my `PATH` environment variable, and both contain the file `mpicxx`

Comment: It looks like a typo: mpi.cxx? This is a build problem with the makefile itself. Alas, it'll be a day or two before I can look at it properly. Have you asked the TACS people about this?

Comment: No, it isn't a typo, it's the name of the MPI-enabled C++ compiler. Anyway, thank you for your availability, but using Ubuntu for Windows proved to be effective up to a certain point (please see the comments to the question), so probably the MSYS2 solution is no longer worth investigating.

Comment: OK, fair enough.