# How do I properly set up a Makefile for NASM x86 for GNU make on Windows? (Solved - file files were not in the directory I though they were)

Tags: assembly, makefile, nasm, gnu-make, chocolatey

I have been watching [this video](https://youtu.be/9t-SPC7Tczc?si=3qWHQUmqCXJ5UHoB&t=504) (he starts creating the Makefile at 8:24), but since he is on Linux and I am on Windows (I'm guessing that is the reason anyway), the 'make' command does not seem to work for me.

So I installed GNU Make through Chocolatey, which according to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532234/how-to-run-a-makefile-in-windows) is supposed to "Run as if trying the Makefile on a native Linux environment", but I got this error:

```
D:\assembly\OS>make
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/main.asm', needed by 'build/main.bin'.  Stop.
```

The Makefile is in the 'OS' directory, and is called just that 'Makefile', with no file name extensions.

```
D:\assembly\OS>dir
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is C14D-581B

 Directory of D:\assembly\OS

07/01/2024  04:32 PM    <DIR>          .
06/01/2024  11:00 PM    <DIR>          ..
07/01/2024  02:07 PM    <DIR>          build
07/01/2024  11:48 AM               307 Makefile
07/01/2024  04:32 PM    <DIR>          src
               1 File(s)            307 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  174,669,336,576 bytes free
```

I then realised that a GNU Makefile actually looks different to what was in the video. So am I missing parts of the command, or do I need to turn this:

```
ASM=nasm

SRC_DIR=src
BUILD_DIR=build

$(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img: $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
    cp $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img
    truncate -s 1440k $(BUILD_DIR)/main_floppy.img

$(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin: $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm
    $(ASM) $(SRC_DIR)/main.asm -f bin -o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.bin
```

into a Makefile that GNU Make can use?

Please keep in mind that I have never used a Makefile before, and thank you.

Comment: I realize you've addressed this in in your question, but to be explicit please include in your question the output of running `dir` in the same directory in which you are running `make`. The *content* you show looks fine; the error indicates that `make` simply isn't able to find the file.

Comment: The contents of the file won't matter until you sort out what's causing the **no makefile found** part of the error.  On Linux you'd use `strace -efile make` to figure out where and how it was trying to open a file called Makefile; probably there's a Windows equivalent, but it's probably more work to install and it looks like you're making boot floppies, not Windows programs, so you wouldn't need it for debugging the NASM programs you're going to write. (That Makefile looks valid to me, for GNU Make, as long as the indents are tabs not spaces.)

Comment: I corrected my mistake. Makefile was not where I thought it was, so moved it into OS, sorry about that. I then tried again but got a different error. The indents are indeed tabs though.

Comment: Nevermind, I just realised that 'src\main.asm' did not exist either, because it is 'src\main\main.asm'.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, problem was that `src\main.asm` does not exist, because it is `src\main\main.asm`.